# How do I print the contents of my local directory in PSFtp?

Tags: psftp

I can type `dir` to print the contents of the remote working directory.

I can type `lpwd` to print the name of the local directory.

What command do I use to print the contents of the local directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [this guide](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html) you can use `!dir` (for example) to run a local command by prefixing with `!`.

In bash you can use `lls` to display a "local ls", so I don't know if `ldir` would work in your case, but you can try and see.

Comment: Thanks! I tested out both `lls` and `ldir` and neither one works. But the `!` did the trick.